# Steps to implement Let's Encrypt with cPanel

Tags: web-hosting, https, security-certificate

I am implementing to adopt a site from `http` to `https`, I am using the `Let's Encrypt` in `cPanel`, I am in a shared hosting environment.

This is how I implement it:

1. Site in maintenance mode
2. Issue the SSL Certificate
3. Adding this code in `.htaccess`:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
4. Deleting all sessions in `session folder` to redirect them in login page. Or delete the all the cookies stored in database.
5. Test it
6. Maintenance mode is off

Is this the right thing to do? If not, please do tell me how to do it.

**Update**

I tested this `.htaccess` code to follow the guidelines of https://hstspreload.org:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>
```

This me a medium warning:

> Warning: Unnecessary HSTS header over HTTP The HTTP page at
>   http://example.com sends an HSTS header. This has no effect over HTTP,
>   and should be removed.

Comment: If the results of step 5. Test it, show that it worked, then seems good. Deleting the cookies in the database might be extreme. Do the cookies store user preferences that they will be unhappy about loosing? Might consider adding step 2.5 Test HTTPS functionality, before doing the forced redirection.

Comment: I tested this in localhost, I need to clear the cache (Mozilla FireFox) inorder for the `rewrite` to work.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver how I can **test https functionality**?

Comment: Before you force the redirection, try to load the page in HTTPS manually. Browser address bar type `httpd://example.com` obviously changing it to your domain name. If you have multiple domains in the cert, do that for _every_ domain listed. Then it's safe to force the redirects. Nothing says "oops" like redirecting to a dead page, or a misconfigured security cert.

Comment: [this plugin](https://github.com/Prajithp/letsencrypt-cpanel) for cPanel/WHM worked for me.

Comment: @Jan it likely does work, but since it is easy to include letsencrypt with cpanel's autossl, why not use what is already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run a web hosting business.  Hundreds of clients are (or aren't if they are lazy) switching to https via free LetsEncrypt certificates.

To be honest, I think you are overcomplicating things.  Install the SSL for the domain, then without changing anything, try using https and see how you go.

You might find a bunch of mixed-content warnings when viewing the developer tools console.  This is one of the most important steps as if there is any mixed content i.e. files included using http, you will not see a *secure* padlock.

There is no need to put a site into maintenance mode.  Even if you have the certificate installed, people can still use the legacy http while you are testing.

Then when your are satisfied it is working, add the code to your .htaccess file.

Here's how you test:  go to htps://example.com and see if there is a padlock in the address bar.  If there is, it is working.  If there is still an *insecure* notification, back to developer tools to look for the problems.

Comment: okay I will do this, is LetsEncrypt will be free after it expires?

Comment: LetsEncrypt needs to be renewed when it expires (3 months).   It is free to renew, but it happens often enough that renewals should be automated.

Comment: LetsEncrypt is most often automated, either via cpanel AutoSSL or if it is set up to do so on the server.  If you don't have root access, check with your host, it won't be long before LetsEncrypt becomes the standard.  They have already disrupted the entire SSL financial model...good on them...it was a rort.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do it as you propose. My suggestion gives you more control over the process resulting as as few errors for your visitors as possible:

- Implement LetsEncrypt / https but don't set any redirects yet
- Now type `https://` in your url and check it yourself. Do/fix as much test as you can/like<sup>1</sup>.
- If you're confident you've got most of it, get a group of users which you tell about the https to do the same (or redirect *just this group*), usage always reveals more problems.
- When you feel you've done all you can, implement the redirect to https <sup>1</sup>
- Keep checking your reports, possible 404's etc. Again, real usage always reveals errors you haven't found, be prepared for this (if you're lucky it a simply typo).
- After a sufficient amount of time, [implement HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), this way your site isn't accessable via http.

<sup>1</sup> I suggest you [link to external files like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just): `//www.example` without either `http:` or `https:` in the URI
<sup>2</sup> No need to remove sessions as they either transfer with you to to the https (unlikely) or they simply expire on the spot. Your users will have to login again if they're switched to https (you might want to give them a heads up).

Comment: I got this error from mozilla firefox http://imgur.com/a/hwiXU, though no details appeared.

Comment: It worked now and this error appeared `Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.`, 1273 of them. Even in `http://` this error appeared.

Comment: in `setcookie` should I set the secure flag to true?

Comment: all the links in the files are starting with `/folder/myfiles.ext`, except for facebook's meta properties, that's all I need to change, right?

Comment: You might want to get someone more skilled to look at your code, because you've just got erors in 4 different parts of your website, which all require another solution. Unfortunally, this site is not the type of forum to help you with all these types or errors.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation to be found about the subject

Comment: good day! how can I use hsts in https? https://hstspreload.org suggested to me that `The HTTP page at http://domain.com sends an HSTS header. This has no effect over HTTP, and should be removed.`

Comment: The link provided in my answer explains it better than I can do in a comment